# How to use for loop to pull & append historic data from Coinbase Pro?

Tags: python, api, coinbase-api

Apologies in advance I'm quite new to this.

My objective is to get a .csv file of historic BTC/USD data in OHLC format for the 15 minute timeframe, between 1 Jan 2018 - current day. I am working with the Coinbase Pro API.

I have the following so far:

```
    import requests
    import pandas as pd
    import time
    from datetime import datetime,timedelta
    apiUrl = "https://api.pro.coinbase.com"

    sym = "BTC-USD"

    barSize = "900"

    delta = timedelta(minutes = 15)
    timeEnd = datetime.now()
    timeStart = timeEnd - (300*delta)

    timeStart = timeStart.isoformat()
    timeEnd = timeEnd.isoformat()

    parameters = {
        "start":timeStart,
        "end":timeEnd,
        "granularity":barSize
    }

    data = requests.get(f"{apiUrl}/products/{sym}/candles",
        params = parameters,
        headers = {"content-type":"application/json"})

    df = pd.DataFrame(data.json(),
        columns = ["time","low","high","open","close","volume"])

    df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], unit='s')

    df = df[["date","open","high","low","close"]]

    print(df)
```

The api is limited to 300 candles per request.

The things I can't figure out:

- how to get a for loop to work to automate the process
- how to get the output into a .csv file to get the python to append the relevant data when the code is run

Any help really would be appreciated.

Comment: if you don't know how many loops you need then use `while`-loop.

Comment: maybe first create normal list with data (rows) and append new data to this list - and at the end convert this list to dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using pandas already you can use the `date_range` method to generate your intervals.

```
intervals = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2022-05-17', freq='15T')
for interval in intervals:
   # query coinbase api
   # set up your data frame
```

To concatenate data frames you can use the `concat` method.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```

And if you have a data frame you can write it to a csv file with the `to_csv` method.

```
df.to_csv('path-to-file.csv')
```

Putting it all together...

```
_df = pd.DataFrame()
intervals = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2022-05-17', freq='15T')
for interval in intervals:
   # query coinbase 
   # setup df from json
   # concat _df and df from this iteration 
   _df = pd.concat([_df, df])
 # finally save it
 df.to_csv('coinbase-btc.csv')
```

It would probably make sense for you to separate the work to download the data from parsing the data. For instance, if you save each request's json data (from `requests.get(url).json()`) to a file you can work with that data later without needing to make more network requests. Useful if you decide later you want to look at other attributes in the data, you won't have to make all those requests again.

```
# download.py 
intervals = pd.date_range(...)
for interval in intervals:
   # setup coinbase url from time interval
   data = requests.get(url).json()
   with open(f'downloads/{time_of_interval}.json') as f:
     f.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Now you can run the parse.py script to make use of that data.

```
# parse.py
from glob import glob
import json
files = glob('downloads/*.json')
for file in files:
   data = json.loads(open(file).read())
   df = pd.DataFrame(data.json(),
    columns = ["time","low","high","open","close","volume"])
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this, trying to figure out exactly how to utilise this but must admit i am still lost :'). 

following the separating the work idea, what would the scripts look like as a whole, if you don't mind? struggling to piece it together :(

Comment: Two separate scripts.. download.py and parse.py . You run each separately. python ./download.py and then after it finishes you run python ./parse.py I would start with a very small time range, like one or two hours worth of data so it doesn't take too long. Once it works as expected then you can increase the time range.